# Sorting dataset in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I'm trying to sort the data,however the names do not get sorted when I jump from one page to another.

```
return new dao_StudentGroupStudents().GetNewStudentbyGroup(bureauId, search, groupId, currentPage, pageSize, out totalCount);

    /// <summary>
    /// Get All the students from that Bureau.
    /// </summary>

    public DataSet GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int? GroupId, int? BureauID)
    {
        DataSet ds = new dao_StudentGroup().GetDataSet(null, null, BureauID);
        ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "grouptitle asc";
        return ds;
    }
```

I'm typing this in and now I get Cannot find column columnName.

public DataSet GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int? GroupId, int? BureauID)
        {
    DataSet ds = new dao_StudentGroup().GetDataSet(null, null, BureauID);

```
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "columnName ASC";

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();

return ds;
```

}

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: So then its sorted correctly on the first page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataSet ds = new dao_StudentGroup().GetDataSet(null, null, BureauID);
ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "grouptitle asc";
ds.Tables[0] = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();
return ds;
```

**UPDATE**

You can simply do this then:

```
public DataSet GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int ? GroupId, int ? BureauID) 
{
    DataSet ds = new dao_StudentGroup().GetDataSet(null, null, BureauID);

    ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "grouptitle asc";        
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: ds.Tables[0] produces an error. proptery or indexes system.Datadatatablescollection.this[int] Cannot be assigned to is is read only

Comment: I'm getting this error now Error 6 'BusinessObjects.StudentGroupManager' does not implement interface member 'BusinessObjects.Contracts.IStudentGroupManager.GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int?, int?)'. 'BusinessObjects.StudentGroupManager.GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int?, int?)' cannot implement 'BusinessObjects.Contracts.IStudentGroupManager.GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int?, int?)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Data.DataSet'. C:\workspace\DOP.IT.Training\Development\MS\BusinessObjects\StudentGroupManager.cs 11 18 BusinessObjects

Comment: The second "=" in the DataTable dt is giving me an invalid expression term and the ds. is giving me an "; expected"

Comment: @user2208126: Sorry, that was a typing mistake. I have updated the code. Try it once!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following. Remember, you can't assign value to ds.Table[] back. Hence you need to create a new datatable and add it to either new or existing dataset

```
    ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "columnName ASC";

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();
```

Comment: = is giving me an invalid expression term

Comment: I'm getting this error now Error 6 'BusinessObjects.StudentGroupManager' does not implement interface member 'BusinessObjects.Contracts.IStudentGroupManager.GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int?, int?)'. 'BusinessObjects.StudentGroupManager.GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int?, int?)' cannot implement 'BusinessObjects.Contracts.IStudentGroupManager.GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int?, int?)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Data.DataSet'. C:\workspace\DOP.IT.Training\Development\MS\BusinessObjects\StudentGroupManager.‌​cs 11 18 BusinessObjects

Comment: I was able to compile the above code without any error. By looking at your code above, it seems that there is something else which is causing the issue.

Comment: I'm putting this in and I get Cannot find column columnName.   public DataSet GetAllStudentGroupByBureau(int? GroupId, int? BureauID) { DataSet ds = new dao_StudentGroup().GetDataSet(null, null, BureauID); ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "columnName ASC"; DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(); return ds; }

Comment: Obviously columnName means the name of the field you want to sort on. You need to change it to original column name, it was just for reference/example only

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
    //convert DataSet table to DataView  
    DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; 

    //apply the sort   
    dv.Sort = "grouptitle ASC"; 

    //save back into our dataset  
    ds.Tables[0] = dv.ToTable();
```

Comment: ds.Tables[0] produces an error.  proptery or indexes system.Datadatatablescollection.this[int] Cannot be assigned to is is read only

Answer (score 0):

DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

```
dv.Sort = "grouptitle ASC"; 

ds = dv.ToTable();
```

try these

default it comes in ds.table[0] no need to menstion it